# Most efficient way to handle tasks

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows form program that's running 24/7 and about every 15 minutes does some work and then has to make roughly 5000 http calls and I don't need to wait or get any results from the calls just simply hit the http API and move on. I have the http call as a separate sub and what I'm doing now is just spawning a new thread for each call. This works fine on a high CPU machine but when I run on a hosted machine with limited CPU's I get about 1/5 of those threads error with an HTTP timeout.

So my question is how do I process 5000+ sub calls independently of my main thread in a way that will process them as quick as possible but not block my application

This is the basic code now:

```vb
for i = 1 to 5000
    Dim thread As New Thread(
        Sub()
            sendtoapi(i)
        End Sub
    )
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    Thread.Start()
next i

Private Sub sendtoapi(i as integer)
    Dim result As String = ""
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Using Client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        result = Client.DownloadString("https://apiurl/addnumber?num=" & i)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: How is this code being triggered? I want to know more details about what the main thread is that would be blocked. In a Forms app the main thread is typically the UI thread, message loop, and it doesn't seem like a good way to run something like this. Like does this code originate on the UI thread, like from  a Forms.Timer? I would say that's a bad way to start it. It shouldn't be triggered in such a way that it's going to stop your main thread. You should provide those details, and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Feel I'm thinking along the same lines as djv here.  While completely agree that using threads/async etc to not block the ui is great, in this case it seems like your probably started in the wrong place.  Perhaps this function that polls the urls might be better suited to something like a console app running on a schedule or a windows service.

Comment: @Hursey +1 for windows service, I was thinking the same exact thing. But I'll answer it according to a WinForms app sitting open 24/7

Comment: Note that you can do `Task`-based asynchronous processing without necessarily using `Async` and `Await`.  If you want to throttle the rate at which tasks are active, you could set up a queue of work to do, seed an initial block of tasks, and use `Task.WhenAny` to capture when one is completed to replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could limit the number of threads with the Task Parallel Library. Namely, `Parallel.For`. This would be a great replacement for your `For` loop.

```vb
Parallel.For(1, 5001, Sub(i) sendtoapi(i))
```

Since you do run from a form timer, then you can continue doing that and make a minor change by using the `Async/Await` mechanic.

```vb
Private WithEvents Timer1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer _
    With {.Enabled = True, .Interval = 15 * 60 * 1000}

Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Await Task.Run(Sub() Parallel.For(1, 5001, Sub(i) sendtoapi(i)))
End Sub
```

This doesn't actually create a new thread, but uses an existing thread from the threadpool. Well, inside the TPL will certainly create new threads :) but `Async/Await` doesn't by itself.

You could totally take it off the UI with a `System.Threading.Timer` and not need to worry about blocking the UI. This runs on a threadpool thread, and the TPL will manage whether it utilizes threadpool threads or feels the need to spawn new threads. It will keep your system in control either way.

```vb
Private runTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf run, Nothing, 0, 15 * 60 * 1000)

Sub run(state As Object)
    Parallel.For(1, 5001, Sub(i) sendtoapi(i))
End Sub
```

Comment: I did oversimplify the code because it's about 15k lines of code. Basically the program is running on a normal timer on the UI thread. Every 15 minutes it downloads about 5k sets of iot sensor data processes that data. That is done locally and very quickly and is done item by item the entire process takes roughly 2 minutes. As those items process we need make an api call to update the new sensor data. If I have it make those calls and wait for the response (I don't need the response) then the total time balloons to 10 minutes. So what I need is pro process just those calls separately but quick

Comment: Yes this would be better as a console app or better yet as a webapp but it's too much for me to rewrite at this time.

Comment: @GrahamBallard according to your comment, I just updated my answer.

Comment: Basically there's a lot more stuff in the For loop that I omitted, but needs to continue to process as quick as possible while the 5000 subsequent sendtoapis are handled separately from the for loop but still processed as quick as the machine can

Comment: Parallel.For will handle that. It will load up the CPU as much as it can, without overloading it. The `For` creating threads will just create as many threads as quickly as it can and leave no time to actually run the threads after a while.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm struggling to adapt it to my situation. I don't need each step of the for loop to be in a thread, just the call to the sendapi. If I implement your suggestion then the entire processing of each sensor data point would be on its own thread instead of simply the api call part of it

Comment: @GrahamBallard you can see how I can't come up with an answer for your situation if you don't post all the code? At least all the relevant code. This answers the question you've asked

Comment: @GrahamBallard maybe make another question which illustrates the entire problem